# Get Firefox to stop asking for confirmation when downloading .hdr files

Tags: firefox, download, file-types

Every time I download an HDR file, Firefox prompts me asking what to do. I want to download the image 100% of the time, but I can't get Firefox to understand this. I am required to select "Save File" and then click "Okay".

[image]

after reading this page about [changing download actions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file) I thought I might be able to specify "save file" as the action for .hdr files. But it doesn't appear in the list.

[image]

After a bit more digging, I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/801903/567432) to a more general version of my question (not specific to HDR files). And I also studied [this page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf) as a reference. But even after I modify **mimetypes.rdf** the behavior of Firefox doesn't change.

Here's what I added:

`<RDF:Seq RDF:about="urn:mimetypes:root">`

```
<RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:image/hdr"/>
```

`</RDF:Seq>`

```
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:image/hdr"
                   NC:fileExtensions="hdr"
                   NC:description="HDR Image"
                   NC:value="image/hdr"
                   NC:editable="true">
    <NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:handler:image/hdr"/>
  </RDF:Description>

  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:handler:image/hdr"
                   NC:alwaysAsk="false"
                   NC:saveToDisk="true"
                   NC:useSystemDefault="false"
                   NC:handleInternal="false">
    <NC:externalApplication RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:externalApplication:image/hdr"/>
  </RDF:Description>
```

What could I be doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox does not use `mimetypes.rdf` any more, using instead the file `handlers.json`.

However, modifying this file will not help, because of the way that the website
[hdrihaven.com](https://hdrihaven.com/) encodes its answers.

The website tells the browser the following in the header of the download file:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

This just defines the download file as a stream of bytes, not as a `HDR` type.
This is why Firefox does not offer you the option to remember the action,
since the type is not defined. Trying to force it in `handlers.json` will
have a much larger effect on future downloads than just for HDR files,
as this Content-Type is much used in many cases.

You might try to contact the website Support and ask that they change
the header to:

```
Content-Type: application/hdr
```

This will allow you to define a default download action for HDR files.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanation!